# How to select classes that have dash "-" with jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

Suppose I want to select the following `html` with `jsoup`:

```
<p class="foo bar-baz">Hello World!</p>
```

I can select it from the `Document` object `doc` with `doc.select("p.foo")`. This look for paragraphs with class foo. I want to be more specific so I then try to go with `doc.select("p.foo.bar-baz")`. I know I can specify additional classes if I separate with dot however in the example above the dash seems to be causing problems. What do I need to do to also select class `bar-baz`?

Comment: what error gives you when you try to search bar-baz?

Comment: @B.J. A.A. Null pointer exception

Comment: can you post your code and the full error log? that would be more helpful

Comment: I can't right now. But are you saying that the following code looks right? I was thinking the dash was causing problems and maybe it needed some escaping or something else to fix it.

Comment: since i can't tell what os going on in your code or the erro log, i think the problem is that doc object is null, hence the null pointer error.

Comment: It would help if you post a full example that causes this error. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve
I do not think that JSoup has problems with dashes

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that I was relying on the html from developers tools in `chrome` but the html of the `Document` object was different. It's not the same code but what happened essentially was that `chrome` would show this:

```
<p class="foo bar-baz">Hello World!</p>
```

When the `html` of the `Document` object in reality only had this:

```
<p class="foo">Hello World!</p>
```

Naturally that was the reason for the null pointer. I then tried to select elements with dashes and it had problem dealing with them (as pointed by luksch in a comment above).

Iam not sure why they would show different html but now I know I can only rely on the `Document` html to select elements.

Comment: HTML visible in developer tools is often different because many pages modify DOM with JavaScript after page was loaded. To see original document don't use browser's debuggers/inspectors but always check original page source with 'View page source' option. Usually CTRL+U.